# Excel VBA REST API connection POST json syntax error

Tags: json, excel, vba, oracle, rest

I am trying to set up a REST API Post call to save excel data into an Oracle database however I am having an issue with the POST call.

Error Message:{"message": "ORA-01400 cannot insert Null into (....\"NUMBER\")"}

```
Sub PostTry()
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
URL = "http:TESTURL"
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "ContentType", "application/json"
Dim Json As String
Json = "{""number"":""123456"", ""DATE_TESTED"":""01-JAN-99"", ""DILUTION"":""10"", ""LOG_LEVEL"":""1""}"
objHTTP.send (Json)
MsgBox (objHTTP.responseText)
MsgBox (Json)
End Sub
```

I have tried adding these things with no help. Error message persisted.

```
'objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
'objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
'objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer <api secret id>"
```

If you have any suggestions for me that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just as a (potentially very stupid) question on my part... should `"number"` be `"NUMBER"` (all caps) ?

Comment: I tried that with no luck..

Comment: Try `"{""number"":123456,...`

Comment: Still, get the same error.

Comment: There's no real way we could know what the problem is here - do you have access to the server-side processing?  Or a reference for the API you can share?

Comment: Have you tried running the same XHR from Google Chrome console? In JavaScript you can model the JSON as an object and not as a simple String. If you still don't manage, then the issue is in the content of your request and should probably be seen on server side (we can't really help you with that). Else, it's  a syntax error in your JSON's string in VBA (in this second case, it makes sense to ask for help to troubleshoot here).

Comment: I downloaded WizTools.org RESTClient to try to POST straight json code into the database and it worked. I used the same URL, and specified application/json; charset=UTF-8. When I submitted in the headers tab I see: Content-Type application/json & Transfer-Encoding chunked so I added objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Transfer-Encoding", "chunked" and charset=""UTF-8""" to my ContentType Header to my code. Still get the same error. So Im thinking its a VBA issue? Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I tried printing my Json string to Excel and then pasting that in the WizTool RestClient and that went through so its something with the Object. Is there a way to embed the body into the object?

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by changing my Object to WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by changing my Object to WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1
so:

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
```